# sudo crontab won't work without /tmp dir: "(CRON) error (create tmpfile)"

Tags: cron, mv, tmp

My system regularly moves `/tmp` to `/snapshot`. [(background)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249868/accidentally-moved-tmp-replacements-wont-persist)

Now I want to create a cronjob that checks every minute if the directory was renamed by the system, and renames it back.

```
$ sudo crontab -l
# ...
*/1 * * * * if [ ! -d "/tmp" ];        then mv /snapshot.0         /tmp;       2>> /home/t/tmp.err1; date >> /home/t/tmp.log1; fi 
*/1 * * * * if [ ! -d "/a" ];          then mv /b                  /a          2>> /home/t/tmp.err2; date >> /home/t/tmp.log2; fi 
*/1 * * * * if [ ! -d "/home/t/tmp" ]; then mv /home/t/snapshot.0  /home/t/tmp 2>> /home/t/tmp.err3; date >> /home/t/tmp.log3; fi 
*/1 * * * * echo "test" #this command definitely doesn't depend on /tmp
```

These work as long as `/tmp` exists. However when `/tmp` gets renamed they all fail with this entry in `/var/log/cron.log`

```
{date and time} ttp CRON[{job-id}]: (CRON) error (create tmpfile)
```

Why does sudo crontab depend on `/tmp`? Is there a way around it?

Comment: "_My system regularly moves /tmp to /snapshot_" this is not normal behaviour. I would class this as a critical fault. What utility have you installed or written that does this?

Comment: @roaima I wish I knew! Please refer to the linked post at the beginning for why it might have happened.

Comment: I looked at the linked post and although you've asked much the same question there you haven't really got a concrete answer as to _why_ it happens.

Comment: @roaima That is correct, I don't have an answer to that. I intended to find the root cause with the linked post, but haven't so far. I do not remember installing any utilities that might have caused this, I certainly never intended for this to happen.

Comment: If such a thing happens, what is the workaround ? I mean, can we make cron run without using /tmp ?